# Currency formula field issue in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, formula, currency

In our Salesforce Org, we have enabled multiple currencies and we had setup the dated exchange rates also. We have a child object called requestObject for Opportunity Product. The Opportunity product has a currency field called "price per rec", which is a currency field and it displays the value as shown below.

```
1000.00 INR (11.05 EUR)
```

On the child object requestObj, I have created a formula field with currency as the return type and I am populating it's value as shown below.

```
Opportunity_Product__r.Price_Per_Rec__c (Opportunity_Product__r is the relationship name)
```

However, when I look at the value of "Price Per Rec" field on the child record (requestObj), it is not displaying the value as shown on the Opportunity product. However, it displays the value as shown below.

1000.27 (11.09 EUR)

I am not sure why there is a difference between the values on both records. Please note that INR is the CurrencyIsoCode on the Opportunity product and our corporate currency is EUR.

The values given are just some examples only, not the actual values.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your custom object and formula uses current exchange rate, not dated. Check what's the exchange rate for now vs this opportunity's close date.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.administration_about_advanced_currency_management.htm&type=5

Dated exchange rates are used for opportunities, opportunity products, (...). Dated exchange rates are not used in forecasting, currency fields in other objects, or currency fields in other types of reports. Dated exchange rates are also not used when calculating formula fields with a formula return type of “Currency.”

Comment: Is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: "reactive" You could write something that on every edit of opportunity close date fetches the right exchange rate and recalculates child records, writes it to a helper hidden field maybe. Plus data fix for existing records. "Proactive" scheduled batch job that does something similar?